# Use of 自分 in terms of dialect, formality, and gender

Tags: gender

I was wondering in terms of Tokyo dialect, if there is a difference in gender and formality in the use of 自分 as a reflexive pronoun 'I'?

Answer (score 2):

自分 is sometimes used as a plain (non-reflexive) first-person pronoun, in which case it's used mainly by tough male speakers (e.g., sumo wrestlers, members of 自衛隊). From [日本語の一人称代名詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%BA%E7%A7%B0%E4%BB%A3%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E#%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%EF%BC%88%E3%81%98%E3%81%B6%E3%82%93%EF%BC%89) on Wikipedia:

> **自分（じぶん）**
>
> スポーツ選手など、いわゆる体育会系の男性がよく使用する。刑事ドラマ『西部警察』では渡哲也が演じた主人公・大門圭介が用いた。この他にタレントの風見しんごらも用いる。文章でもしばしば使われる一人称であり、その場合は女性も用いる場合もあるが、改まった文章やビジネス文書では使われない。

Putting this aside, when 自分 is used as a *reflexive* pronoun meaning "myself", I think there is no difference in gender.

Comment: 私見ながら、体育会系に限るならむしろ女性の方がよく使ってる印象があります。男性アスリートであれば「僕」を使う人が一定数いますが、女性ではそれが「自分」になってるんじゃないかと思います。ただ、母数が違うので全体比で言えば少ないでしょうが。